# Send object as parameter in client.PutAsync

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core

I am facing a problem in using PutAsync. PutAsync update an object. Below is my code. (Mongodb database)

Controller Code:

```
     stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(businessUnit);  //businessUnit is updated object
     var contentData = new StringContent(stringData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
     response = client.PutAsync(baseAddress + "/api/BusinessUnit/" + businessUnit.Id, contentData).Result;
```

API Controller Code :

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<string> Put(string id, BusinessUnit businessUnit)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) return "Invalid id !!!";
        return await _businessUnitRepository.Update(id, businessUnit);
    }
```

Given code works good but my problem is in API controller businessUnit parameter's all fields become null instead of id.

My Confusion is, if businessUnit parameter's all fields are null then why its primary key "id" is not null ??

I want to get all fields as parameter in businessUnit object from controller to api controller. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `[FromBody]` attribute to the 'businessUnit' parameter:

```
public async Task<string> Put(string id, [FromBody] BusinessUnit businessUnit)
```

This is called an [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) and allows to map data from HTTP requests to action method parameters:

> `[FromBody]`: Use the configured formatters to bind data from the request body. The formatter is selected based on content type of the request.